# Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api

I am using google.maps.places.Autocomplete, I want city to autocomplete but restrict the autocomplete results to multiple cities, not just one as in the google documentation.

this is what I have

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

    /* restrict to multiple cities? */
    var options = {
       types: ['(cities)'],
       componentRestrictions: {country: "us", "fr"}
    };


    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
</div>
```

Comment: Ironically, this is the first example that I have found for filtering by country.  Thanks!  Where did you go for documentation btw?

Comment: Workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290755/limit-google-maps-of-countries-in-the-autocomplete-list-to-india-usa-and-uk/36064059#36064059

Answer (score 3):

Actually the Places API supports only 1 country as restriction. [ComponentRestrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions)

Answer (score 1):

I am new to google places autocomplete but I think the error is here:

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "us", "fr"}
```

Try this:

```
componentRestrictions: {country: ["us", "fr"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only add 1 country for restrictions.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions