# Need multiple country componentRestrictions in Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need Google Places Autocomplete to give me results from countries: SZ, FR, DE, AT, IT. I know that `componentRestrictions` can operate with only one country. 
So, is there a way to get results with multiple counties in Google Places Autocomplete?

My page is copy-paste from [Place Autocomplete Address Form example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform):

Comment: There is already a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4233) in the Google Maps issue tracker. Currently there is no way to restrict multiple countries by using the `componentRestrictions`.

Comment: Workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290755/limit-google-maps-of-countries-in-the-autocomplete-list-to-india-usa-and-uk/36064059#36064059

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature was introduced in version 3.27 of Maps JavaScript API in January 2017:

> You can now restrict Autocomplete predictions to only surface from multiple countries. You can do this by specifying up to 5 countries in the componentRestrictions field of the AutocompleteOptions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#327

Comment: I wonder why they build in the arbitrary restriction to five countries. Probably because they think US plus oversea departments is enough.

Answer (score 17):

Since version 3.2.7, you can use an array for componentRestrictions. Eg:

```
{ country: ["fr","ch","be"] }
```

The number of countries is, however, restricted to 5.

Comment: Thank you! Here's the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#ComponentRestrictions) that confirms this.

Answer (score 12):

Be careful because if you restrict to "FR", it ignores the French overseas departments.
So to have the cities in all of France, you need:

```
'fr', 'gp', 're', 'mq', 'gf', 'nc', 'yt', 'pf'
```

But since it's more than 5, it's not possible to limit to the whole of France.

Google Maps considers that the French overseas departments are not in France; this is a big problem.

Comment: You can't even get all of the USA, because you'd need US, AS, FM, GU, MH, MP, PR, PW, VI

Answer (score -1):

You can also just omit `componentRestrictions: {country: "XX"}` to return results from anywhere.

```
var options = {
            types: ["geocode"],
            // componentRestrictions: {country: "US"}
        };

this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(autocompleteField), options);
```