# how to limit google autocomplete places to N countries?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I know it is possible to restrict place to 1 country:

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "fr"}
```

But is there a way to restrict to N countries like ["fr", "be"] ?

Comment: You provided the solution in your own question...

Answer (score 3):

componentRestrictions can actually handle up to 5 countries, simply attach the country codes, to an array with 5 Elements.

```
    { country: ["ch","at","fr","gr","mx"] }
```

Google itself says: "`-componentRestrictions` can be used to restrict results to specific groups. Currently, you can use `componentRestrictions` to filter by up to 5 countries. Countries must be passed as as a two-character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code. Multiple countries must be passed as a list of country codes." (Find at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete )

> Note:
>   Question was already answered here: [Need multiple country componentRestrictions in Google Places Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179717/need-multiple-country-componentrestrictions-in-google-places-autocomplete)